# User input passed as a variable to subprocess.call

Tags: python, subprocess, metasploit

Im trying to pass a variable into another program that is being launched. I having issues with the variable working

here is the code
It all works up until the passing of RHOST, metasploit takes it as %RHOST

I need to pass the RHOST variable straight after set RHOSTS . Help please :)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os,sys,re,subprocess
RHOST=raw_input("Enter ipaddress range:")
print ("Your Address range is\n" + RHOST + "!")
subprocess.call("xterm -e msfconsole -x 'sleep 2; use auxiliary/scanner/discovery/arp_sweep; set RHOSTS '%RHOST'; exploit'",shell=True)
end = raw_input('Hit Enter to Exit.')
```

Comment: do you want to pass your RHOST value instead of %RHOST in a call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use string format:

```
"xterm -e msfconsole -x 'sleep 2; use auxiliary/scanner/discovery/arp_sweep; set RHOSTS '\%{0}'; exploit'".format(RHOST)
```

Comment: Be aware that if RHOST comes from an untrusted source, this could lead to security problems is RHOST could contain special shell characters like ' and ;